# How can I disable interactive login for all the members of an active directory group?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, login

I have a group of users that I'm setting up as test users.  I want to make it so that no one can log onto the domain with these accounts, but they need to have active exchange mailboxes since this is what I am testing.  I put all the test users in the same group.  Can I set a security policy that will do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable users/groups from local login. What you can do is remove the "Users" group from the 'local login' privilege, then add back the rest of the people.

The settings are in Group Policy, Machine Settings, Security Settings, Local Policies, User Rights, Log On Locally. Be very careful you don't lock everyone out of everything (ie, apply this to an OU (or restrict it to a group) of just one computer, then test.

Comment: That works for a single machine, but how can I apply this to all the computers in the tree?

Comment: Open Group Policy Management Console from the Domain Controller. There will be a Domain Policy in there, right click and edit it (or a better practice is to add another GPO and link it). **Be extremely careful** though, it will apply automatically to all clients within minutes of changing the values (without having to save or close the GPMC, and assuming everything is working correctly).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat.  Basically, you can use group policy to configure the workstation “Log on locally” setting, which controls who can log on interactively to a Windows machine, you could set the accounts "log on to," you could but these users in a gropu and then apply a deny locon locally.

Deny logon locally

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment

There are analagous settings for terminal services as well.